# Obtener datos dentro de un ID aleatorio - Firebase

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos, firebase

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion para android y he llegado al punto en el que tengo todos los productos, cuando le doy agregar al carrito, añado el ID del producto dentro de un nuevo child dentro del usuario actual. Si dentro de ese nuevo child llamado "productos" añado los ID de todos los prodocutos que le doy click al añadir al carrito, queda algo asi: **-L_ZXuTy2aVKuzWA1Y6r: "true"**. Donde el id del producto lo guardo como child y le doy un valor "true".

Con el siguiente codigo funciona perfectamente obteniendo una lista completa de todos estos productos que he añadido al carrito y luego esta lista la comparo con el child donde estan guardados estos productos.

Codigo:

```
followingList = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
        .child( FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
        .child("productos");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        followingList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            followingList.add(snapshot.getKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }});
```

Pero quiero que en vez de guardarse dentro del child "productos" directamente, se cree un ID aleatorio con el metodo push y dentro de cada ID unico se añada el ID del producto que añadi a carrito.

Actualmente hasta ahi puedo llegar, pero no se como buscar dentro de un ID aleatorio todos los ID de productos que esten dentro de: child "productos" -> ID aleatorio -> ID del producto. Este ultimo es el que quiero obtener de todos los ID aletorios que se encuentren.

```
"productos" : {
"-LaSV9Nxwrz58Oe8sLwE" : {
  "-LaQoiF-_v_1BsEiqU7v" : true
},
"-LaSXD7-B6E51QRMMoWp" : {
  "-LaQoiF-_v_1BsEiqU7v" : true
}
```

Comment: Pero ¿por qué creas tantos IDs aleatorios? ¿Estudiaste bien cuál es el modelo de datos que te conviene para tu app?. Es un punto muy delicado en Firebase, porque no funciona como las bases de datos tradicionales y porque uno no tiene demasiada práctica en No SQL. Cuando organizas los datos, tienes que pensar también en cómo vas a necesitar consultarlos, ese es otro punto crucial en Firebase si no te quieres encontrar luego en un callejón sin salida. Y otra cosa, dependiendo de si es RealTime Database  o Firestore, puede haber diferencias en el modelo de datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Puedes recomendarme una base de datos que sea como Firebase en el sentido que te da el servicio de servidores y toda la infraestructura pero que sea SQL? Y creo varios ID aleatorios porque un producto puede ser comprado 2 veces por el mismo usuario pero con caracteristicas diferentes, entonces por cada producto creo un ID para separarlos.

Comment: Si quieres quedarte en el ámbito de SQL, una alternativa interesante podría ser [`Amazon RDS`](https://aws.amazon.com/es/rds/). Sólo lo he visto de pasada. En el enlace puedes verificar si es lo que buscas y hacer pruebas. Firebase no es mala alternativa, pero habría que meterse un poco dentro del ámbito NO SQL, como funciona, etc. He visto posts de gente que recibe facturas altas debido a una mala estructura de datos en Firebase o debido a usar mal las consultas (por ejemplo, trayendo en el snapshot toda la base de datos y cosas así lo cual es una app con muchos usuarios sería gravísimo).

Comment: @A.Cedano Casualmente estaba viendo Amazon RDS. Soy novato aun en estos temas de los servicios que te dan, mi pregunta es si funciona como Firebase que te da el alojamiento y todo, simplemente lo conectas a la App y realizas las consultas. Porque estoy viendo que funciona con varias instancias de base de datos, ya sea Oracle, Mariadb...

Comment: No sé si funciona así, no lo conozco ni lo he usado nunca. Ayer fue cuando leí algo sobre Amazon precisamente investigando sobre algunas dudas que tengo sobre Firebase y alguien hablaba de Amazon como alternativa. Habría leer la doc para ver cómo  es el servicio y qué posibilidades ofrece. A mi me parece que es similar a Firebase en muchas cosas sólo que usando bases de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Con esta linea

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

        }
```

Obtenes todos los hijos debajo de un snapshot, lo que deberias hacer es lo siguiente.

1.- Usar ese for bajo el child productos, esto te va a devolver todas las keys debajo de producto

2.- Adentro del for pones un if para comparar si el valor que estas buscando esta entre todas las keys, una vez que encontraste el valor usas `getKey()` para obtener el padre de ese valor, que seria el id del producto en cuestion que contiene ese id aleatorio con true

Pseudo

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     if(tu_key.equals(alguna_de_las_keys)
            //String producto = snapshot.getKey();
        }
```